# Modal to Double View and NSUserdefaults/CoreData. Where should I begin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Ok, so this is going to be long, and may be confusing.  I am using Xcode 4 w/ iOS SDK 4.3

I will describe my scenario, and what I need.  I am fairly new to Objective-C, but I do understand basic concepts etc. I am not asking for someone to do this for me, I am simply asking for some help with how I should go about starting, doing certain things, and making it work smoothly.

I will try and explain what I need in most detail, to prevent confusion. I am truly sorry if this is lengthly, and I appreciate any help what-so-ever. I have been struggling with this for a good week now.
I have a tab-based iPhone application, and the first tab is a Welcome page. I need a first-time use page, which will appear if only it is not filled out.
I will now simply list what I am trying to do.

If the user has not filled out the setup page yet, modally display it after application launch. For simplicity, I will refer to the first"setup" page as "ModalSetup1"
On ModalSetup1, there are 2 segmented controllers, and one switch.

- The first has 5 options, and the different options are: 8,9,10,11,12.
- The second segmented control has 2 options, they will have text labels, but I am not sure how I am going to implement this (string or int?).
- The switch is an optional selection to do another part in the setup.  If selected, the "done" button at the top right of the screen will change to a "Next" button, and when you hit Next, it will take you to another part of the setup (ModalSetup2), instead of closing, which it would do if the switch was set to off.

[image: Here is the first picture, as I can not directly post images yet.]

Now, there is another part which might even get more complicated, but I will explain that later (ModalSetup2).  I don't even know if you can display 2 different views modally…
What I need is the segmented controller options to be saved, and be able to be retrieved from other tabs/views. The settings won't actually display on the other Views, but it will actually tell the other views to act. Use an "If Statement"?

Now, this part is the next section in the setup.  It is "ModalSetup2".
There are 8 buttons, and when each button is hit, I need a picker to be displayed similarly to how a keyboard is displayed.  All 8 of these pickers will display the same content, but each is individual as they are each different, and I need a selection from each one. In the pickers, it needs to display 3 columns.  Once the user has completed filling out the pickers, they will hit done, and all of the data will be saved, and should be able to be pulled and used in other views of my App.

[image: Here is the second picture.]

I am having trouble with pulling the data that is selected (currently saved via NSUserDefaults) and displaying it on another view.  Another problem I am having is switching to another view Modally, while still being able to switch back to my original view.

If you need any more info, just let me know.  I am adding pictures in right now, so please be patient.

Comment: You could show us the code that saves/loads from NSUserDefaults...

Comment: I have actually just removed it, as It was actually sampled, and no longer pertained to the current code. I am having trouble saving the settings with the segmented controllers.

Comment: I have actually got the NSUserdefaults working with a segmented control. All i need help with now is the 8 pickers. Any Suggestions?